# Can I get infected by just downloading (not opening) file on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware

Today I received some e-mail to Thunderbird. It had image attached that I clicked:
[image]

Which sent me to onedrive.live.com/download?... and automatically downloaded .tgz file. I am not even sure if the file was really .tgz or it was fake extension. I didn't open the file, but Windows still made some preview inside download folder:

[image]

I am worried because Windows made preview which I guess means it already opened the file automatically even if I didn't click it? Is there risk that my laptop is infected even if I didn't open the file and I just deleted it? Could I get infected because Windows made automatic preview without opening the file?

Answer (score 2):

The file may be malicious if it was advertised as `.pdf` but pointed
to a `.tgz` file, so you did well to delete it.
You should also clear the Recycle Bin, just in case.
(It's always possible that for some reason the PDF file was packaged inside
the `.tgz`, but is not worth checking.)

Note: Your browser should **not** be set to automatically download files of any type.
It's much better to be able to cancel the download via a dialog, especially if the name
of the download file does not correspond.

Answer: What you see is not a preview but just the list of all downloaded files.
Neither the browser nor Windows have opened the file.
If you didn't open the file yourself, then you are safe.

If you want to be extra-sure, you may use your antivirus to do a deep (slow) scan
of your disk.